# How to stop mplayer from terminal after a specific interval of time

Tags: shell, terminal, mplayer

I want to make a shell script that runs a particular song in Mplayer for a particular time and then stops ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPlayer has this functionality built in – e.g.,

```
$ mplayer -endpos 1.7 my_song.flac
```

will play the first 1.7 seconds of my_song.flac.